# Zend 2 - Display Global Form Errormessages

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

Zend 2 latest

As i know i can set different errormessages to each zend-form element.

`$oForm->get('myElement')->setMessages(array('My defined errormessage - for THIS one element'));`

Is there a way to define a global error message into the form, which would be (for eg.) displayed at the top of the form, or do i have to insert this function by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flashMessenger helper of zf2.
The full documentation on how to use it can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html)

Comment: thanky for your answer. i know about the flashmessenger, i use it for global messages. thought more about a form related messenger, but seems not implemented into form :-/, thx anyway